# Swift: Error when trying to call a closure in an instance function

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to define a class including a closure to update its variables. The class definition looks like:

```
class Layout
{
    let name: String
    var  choHash: [String: String]
    var jungHash: [String: String]
    var jongHash: [String: String]
    let updater: ([String: String], [String: String], [String: String] -> ())

    init(name: String, choHash: [String: String], jungHash: [String: String], jongHash: [String: String], updater: ([String: String], [String: String], [String: String] -> ()))
    {
        self.name = name
        self.choHash  =  choHash
        self.jungHash = jungHash
        self.jongHash = jongHash
        self.updater = updater
    }

    func update() -> ()
    {
        self.updater(self.choHash, self.jungHash, self.jongHash) // Error here
    }
}
```

So this is pretty much like what I'd do in Ruby, for example. However, XCode shows an error here:

'(@lvalue [String : String], @lvalue [String : String], @lvalue [String : String]) -> $T8' is not identical to '([String : String], [String : String], [String : String] -> ())'

I have two questions:

1. Why does this happen, and how can I address the problem? Especially, why does it comprehends the statement as passing the @lvalue [String: String], instead of [String: String]?
2. Once the problem is solved, will the variables choHash, jungHash and jongHash updated properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this type:

```
([String: String], [String: String], [String: String] -> ())
```

is not a function type.

It’s a 3-tuple containing two dictionaries and a function from dictionary to void.

If you want a function that takes 3 dictionaries, this is the type you need:

```
([String: String], [String: String], [String: String]) -> ()
```

If you amend the type in the `let` and in the `init` argument, it compiles OK.

That said, when you say:

> will the variables choHash, jungHash and jongHash updated properly?

The answer is – probably not.  Are you expecting, when you call `x.update`, for the dictionaries in `x` to be updated by the closure?  If so, they won’t be (unless that closure somehow can get a reference back to `x` itself).  Dictionaries in Swift are passed by value, so unless they are passed as an `inout` parameter nothing the called function can do will alter the values the caller passed in.

Comment: Oh, what a silly mistake. Adding "inout"s, now this code runs flawlessly. Thank you.